# Datasource connection in Java Application

Tags: java, datasource, jndi

How can I configure JNDI DataSource connection for regular Java application packaged into .jar file?

I have DataSource like this [`FooDataSource.xml`]:

```
<datasources>
<local-tx-datasource>
  <jndi-name>FooDS</jndi-name>
  <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/foo</connection-url>
  <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
  <user-name>admin</user-name>
  <password>admin</password>
  <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
  <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
</local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

I have put this file into `Resouces` folder.

Im trying to init connection like this:

```
    DataSource dataSource = null;
    InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();
    dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:/FooDS");
    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    return conn;
```

However it is not working at all. I'm getting error like this while calling `InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext();`

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class:   org.osjava.sj.SimpleContextFactory [Root exception is    java.lang.ClassNotFoundExcepti
on: org.osjava.sj.SimpleContextFactory]
    at   javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:657)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
    at ...DBUtil.getConnection(DBUtil.java:65)
    at ...DBUtil.getFirstFleetCardId(DBUtil.java:133)
    at ...sheduler.MainEntrance.execute(MainEntrance.java:76)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osjava.sj.SimpleContextFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper12.loadClass(VersionHelper12.java:46)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:654)
    ... 8 more
```

What I'm missing?

**EDIT2**
Now im getting error like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ...DBUtil.getConnection(DBUtil.java:67)
    at ...DBUtil.getFirstFleetCardId(DBUtil.java:128)
    at ...MainEntrance.execute(MainEntrance.java:76)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at   org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Where line 67 is: `Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();`

Comment: what do you mean by not working? Any exception/error you see?

Comment: @SMA forgot to add error message. question updated

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a class on the classpath: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osjava.sj.SimpleContextFactory`. You probably should add `simple-jndi-x.xx.jar` to your class path.

Comment: good point, this was a part of a problem, but there is more, question updated

Comment: Concerning your updated question: your datasource is `null`. So my guess is JDNI cannot locate / load the specified datasource